# Normal Distribution Shapiro test failure

Tags: r, normal-distribution

my dataset has 89 observations and it is failing the normal distribution shapiro.test. The qqnorm plot and boxplot looks normal distributed. Please look at the image. The data has p value of 0.0078. Can we use some other test of normality or is there a range of pvalue which is considered near normal ?

```
Response PredictorI PredictorII
39.09 13160 63
46.36 1862 66
48.18 4500 76
53.64 1252000 18
54.55 422783 20
54.55 38697 27
55.00 85961 30
55.45 64253 32
55.91 36069 31
55.45 7045 32
56.36 6200 53
56.59 354742 60
56.82 511581 41
56.36 166387 51
56.52 57667 60
57.27 30992 35
57.27 54572 43
57.30 3960 19
57.27 46163 63
58.18 80235 37
58.18 29988 41
58.18 18494 43
58.18 3618 50
58.18 60602 64
58.18 289505 43
59.09 59298 60
59.09 38753 46
59.10 662918 43
59.09 140522 43
60.00 7334 51
60.91 516668 77
61.54 41335 54
61.82 30250 54
62.73 30993 46
62.73 9523 57
62.73 417148 51
62.73 91662 51
62.73 159931 68
63.64 16000 57
63.64 22945 51
63.64 26693 70
63.64 24205 51
63.64 89032 70
64.52 184428 43
64.91 227903 57
65.45 43817 65
65.45 24778 60
65.45 19043 49
66.36 228852 67
67.27 68913 67
68.18 42774 59
68.18 7260 65
68.42 125000 76
68.42 187215 62
70.00 57584 65
71.82 104864 65
72.73 95000 59
72.73 14200 68
73.64 88108 78
73.64 262342 84
73.64 200000 78
74.55 13778 86
74.55 35560 79
74.55 73680 62
74.55 19685 81
74.55 24885 81
```

Comment: You didn't link your image properly and this isn't really a programming question.  And if you're just going to look for other tests of normality until you find one that gives you the results you want - what is the point of even testing normality in the first place?

Comment: On a more statistical note - why and what are you testing for normality?

Comment: Thanks Dason for your revert. I have a limited sample of 89 and I want to use Parametric tests which have more statistical power and can detect cause and effect among variables better than Non Parametric test. I couldnt get to post images here but qqnorm plot and box plot looks normal. The skewness is near to zero but not exactly zero. I would like to use normality test which is more flexible for sample size of 89. If I had greater sample size it wouldnt have mattered. Do you know how can i post image?

Comment: I can make a guess at distribution symmetry from box plots. but even that is fallible. Normality? No; the box plot leaves out far too much. If you post your 89 values by copying and pasting them as text, it will be easy to produce plots and give you concrete advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tend to sit loose to tests of normality in this context, and indeed all others, on these and other grounds:

1. For very small sample sizes, there is often not enough information for the test to be informative. For larger sample sizes, significance at conventional levels often just means that there is detectable minor deviation from normality that won't bite with what you want to do. There is a zone in the middle and exceptions to both cases, but a test result in itself may be enigmatic.
2. A graph (especially a normal quantile plot) shows more and tells more. There is some circularity in that you need some experience to interpret from the graph what is tolerable and what is serious, but the circularity is not vicious, as experience with what works is a guide.
3. Marginal distributions are important but not the whole story to an analysis. It's how a variable behaves in the main analysis that is crucial. For example, outliers or fat tails or skewness may be important not in themselves but because they mess up a regression. Or conversely, one or more of those features may be explained by corresponding values of the predictors.
4. A graph guides what other action may be taken. Sometimes independent investigation shows that an outlier is just a mistake and should be deleted. I join those who urge that outliers should not be deleted just because they are awkward for an analysis. It's better to change the analysis to match the data than to change the data. Most commonly, a transformation or appropriate link function may help, although again it's not just a matter of a better behaved distribution, but of how this works in the main analysis.

Turning to your data, I see 66 observations (not 89). For what you have shown us, Predictor I leaps out as being the most problematic, but a log transformation works nicely to make it closer to normal. Log 10 was used to make the graph axis labels easier to think about, but logarithms to any convenient base would be fine.  For example $6$ and $5$ mean $10^6$ and $10^5$. (It's not an assumption of regression that any marginal distribution is normal or even symmetric; nevertheless normal and symmetric distributions tend to be better behaved!)

[image]

I don't give full regression results here but they show that your model works better using log Predictor I rather than Predictor I. The added variable plots indicate that the first three observations are rather odd, so there may be more to say there. (The numeric labels such as 1 2 3 are order in the data as you have given them.)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Nick! Really appreciate your looking at it and giving your expert comments. Some how the whole data 89 data points were posted because of limited characters. I will use edit question option now on.

Comment: What I get from your charts is that Response and Predictor II are close to normal distribution and Predictor I with log transformation comes close to normal distribution. In the regression equation these both predictors are significant and should I try log transformation of Predictor I only which might tell more? How to interpret the coefficients of log transformation predictor I?  Also the first three data points will look in. Thanks

Comment: With log transformation there is improvement in R square ...to interpret the log coefficient and transform it back ..now looking at ?

Comment: My suggested model (again from 66 observations, as the full 89 are still not visible) is Response $= b_0 + b_1 \log$ PredictorI $+ b_2 $ PredictorII. There is no sense in which $b_1$ should be transformed to any other scale.  There may be a better model, for example, one that makes more sense given what you know about the variables. As these variables are anonymous, even speculation is impossible without more information.

Comment: Thanks Nick..the data is a subset of green building scores which I am looking at. If I can request your inputs on choice of regression model for the dataset. Can i have your email id?

Comment: It's not very difficult to find an email for me but I don't offer private support such as you seek. Much of the point of a forum like this is that questions, answers and comments are visible to many people.

Comment: sure ..i will post on the forum